# Laravel 5 CORS - XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myapi.com. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cors

I am using Laravel 5 and a library called CORS. I am facing an error that I don't really understand what it is and why it is happening.

I am developing an API that is gonna be used by a website's front-end and an app.

I am trying to do an ajax call to the API:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://myapi.com/call',
  type: 'GET',
  headers: {'Authorization' : 'Bearer token123'},
  crossDomain: true,
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  success   : function(data) { console.log(data);},
  error: function(xhr) {console.log(xhr)}
});
```

However I got this errro:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myapi.com/call. Response for
>   preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500

However, when I remove the following line from the request works fine.

```
headers: {'Authorization' : 'Bearer token123'},
```

EDIT: my config/cors.php

```
'supportsCredentials' => false,
'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
'allowedMethods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT',  'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
'exposedHeaders' => [],
'maxAge' => 0,
'hosts' => [],
```

Any idea about how to solve it?

Comment: Your server is sending a 500 response when it should send a 200. Can you show the relevant server-side responsible for CORS handling? The CORS preflight request is an OPTIONS request done before "non-simple" requests, including requests that have uncommon headers. If you don't know anything about CORS, see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 3):

The following fix worked for me (Laravel 5.4)
You can add the following to the laravel cors middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
     if ($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
       return response(['OK'], 200)->withHeaders([
           'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
           'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE',
           'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
           'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Authorization, Content-Type',
         ]);
     }

     return $next($request)
     ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
     ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE')
     ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
     ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization,Content-Type');
}
```

and for each of your routes which gets preflight requests add a options method too

```
Route::post('/yourroute', 'YourController@index');
Route::options('/yourroute', 'YourController@index');
```

Comment: Athul Raj - you are a life saver bro.  I have been struggling with this issue for the last 2 weeks.  Just the update you suggested to the Middleware solves for it.  No need to write the duplicate routes.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Did you configure CORS on server in laravel, there are couple of option to do the same

```
# one of the way is to add below in .htaccess (modify accordingly)

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

# other options you can refer to below link of laracasts
```

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-5-cors-headers-with-filters/?page=2

Comment: I edited the post and posted CORS' configuration options. Could you take a look?

Comment: narendra, I tried your code modifications on .htaccess and I got the following message:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myapi.com/call. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.


Any advice?